# Why the data value is not passed to controller?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to pass $id to create controller:

```
  <div class="col-lg-2">                     
     {!! Form::open(['route' => ['addkeluarga_form', id]]) !!}             
     {{ Form::submit('Add New', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
     {!! Form::close() !!}
  </div>
```

I try to replace the above code to this but also fail:

```
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('addkeluarga_form', $id) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="POST">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Add!</button>'
                            <input type="hidden" value="StaffKeluarga" />
                            </form>
```

This is the controller:

```
  public function create(Request $request)
{
    $idFromFrontEnd = $request->StaffKeluarga;
    $staffs=DB::select("SELECT id FROM staffs WHERE id = ?", [$idFromFrontEnd]);
    return view('keluarga.add_keluarga', compact('staffs', 'idFromFrontEnd'));    
}
```

It can view the blade but the value for  $idFromFrontEnd is null.
Why it doesn't work?

Comment: I change the code to send the parameter value but still fail

Answer (score 0):

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $idFromFrontEnd = $request->fromForm;
    $staffs=DB::select("SELECT id FROM staffs WHERE id = ?", [$idFromFrontEnd]);
```

Comment: $request->fromForm 'fromForm' is this a syntax?

Comment: it works(can view the blade)..but I check the value of $idFromFrontEnd = $request->fromForm; is null

Comment: Can you check if you have something like this for your form?
<form action="pagetogoto" method="get">
@joun

Comment: You should have a "post" or "get" method defined in your form for the $request to take the value.

Comment: {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'KeluargaController@create', 'route' => ['addkeluarga_form', $id]]) !!}

Comment: is it like this?

Comment: @joun 
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
   First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
   Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
You can try to see if you are able to get the value from the data you input in the form.

Comment: ok..will digest it first and get back to you later..thank you